# Flutter-Issue with Conditional Color within Card Widget

Tags: flutter, colors, widget, conditional-statements

I am new to flutter and trying to change Card() color for a SliverList() I am creating based on multiple String conditions such as 'someText'. Currently, I have the Card() changing color based on a single condition, but I am unable to figure out how to apply multiple conditions to this parameter. I would like to provide multiple string conditions for the color and have different colors as well as a default color if no conditions are met. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context,index) => Card(
                      color: items[index].theTopic =='someText' ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.yellow,

                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () => _navigateToNote(context, items[index]),
                        customBorder: cardShape,),
              childCount: items.length
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continuously add condition in else part, whatever amount of condition you need.

Ex:

```
color: items[index].theTopic =='someText' ? Colors.greenAccent :  items[index].theTopic =='otherText' ? Colors.amber : items[index].theTopic =='anotherText' ? Colors.red : Colors.black, // last black color will become default color
```

Comment: @mlost your welcome! accept and upvote my answer of you found it useful.